# Unable to find stash/apply functionalitit in EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-stash

I'm working with Eclipse Kepler and EGit 3.0.0. Where can I find the GIT stash/apply functionality.

I cannot find stash in the package explorer team pop-up nor anywhere in the *Team Synchronizing* perspective.

Comment: why do you assume that it’s there at all?

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0#Stash_Support states the introduction of stash support.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

After all I found it, hidden in the "Git Repository view":

[image]

Comment: Thanks: I was looking for a way to apply stashed changes and going through the git repo view seems to be the only way.  Note however that if you have uncommitted work and do a switch, Eclipse will offer to stash your changes as one of the options, without requiring you to go through the git repo view.

Answer (score 21):

With Eclipse Mars (Egit Version 4.0.3) you can access the Stash via click on Project ==> Team ==> Stashes:

[image: EGit Stash]

Answer (score 10):

For me, the "AHA" moment was when I realized stashing (in EGit) happens at project level and not at file level. So I spent hours searching in the file context menu with no luck. Right click the project, and there it is...

Answer (score 4):

You can also type CTRL-3 (CMD-3 on Mac) to start quick access and then type "stash" to find and run stash